# How to align left the text?

Tags: html, css

I have the script which has the two steps and I want to align the text for example:

````
Step1 : I am a boy........
my name is Ram```
````

But I want to align the text as

````
Step1 : I am a boy........
        my name is Ram```
````

I tried text-align and align attribute to span.

```css
p.steps {
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<p class="steps"> <span style="color:#BB2812">Step1 : </span> I am a boy................. my name is Ram</p>
<p class="steps"> <span style="color:#BB2812">Step2 : </span> There are many countries but I live in Australia </p>
```

Comment: Check out the CSS option `text-indent`

Comment: A better way would be to put both of them in different spans and align them instead of trying the do that. So, basically one span should keep the word "step" and the other should keep the info for step. that way you'll get that alignment consistently.

Comment: @akaBase when we will see the content in big page it will keep the space between to words.

Comment: @HellBringer419 I tried that but did not get any success.

Comment: add `display:flex` to `.steps` and `white-space:nowrap;` to `span`

Comment: @MuddasarSaiyed Hey lucky for u, people have shown how to do that as answers. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

table layout will do the trick

```css
p.steps {
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display:table; /* here */
}
p.steps span {
  display:table-cell; /* here */
  white-space:nowrap; /* and here */
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="steps"> <span style="color:#BB2812">Step1 : </span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut pellentesque urna at ex fermentum egestas. Nullam convallis nec dolor finibus rhoncus. Nunc neque nisi,</p>
<p class="steps"> <span style="color:#BB2812">Step2 : </span> There are many countries but I live in Australia </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it. You can do it using flexbox.

Add `display: flex` to the `p` element.

```css
p.steps {
  display: flex;

  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.step {
  display: block;
  
  color: #BB2812;
}

.step-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="steps">
  <span class="step">Step 1:</span>

  <span class="step-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada non ex consectetur posuere. Vestibulum in leo tempus dolor pharetra ultricies.
  </span>
</p>

<p class="steps">
  <span class="step">Step 2:</span>

  <span class="step-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada non ex consectetur posuere. Vestibulum in leo tempus dolor pharetra ultricies.
  </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of possible solutions (`table`,`flex`,`text-indent`, etc.) but as long as it is ordered list I would use `ol` and `li` to be **semantically correct**. You can create your own `list-style` like element with `:before` pseudo element which can implement `elementcounter`.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: elementcounter;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 3.5rem;
}
li:before {
  content: "Step " counter(elementcounter) ":";
  counter-increment: elementcounter;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
   <li>I am a boy...<br/> my name is Ram</li>
   <li>There are many countries but I live in Australia</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach you an use `div`.

```css
p.steps {
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <div style="color:#BB2812;    float: left;
    width: 8%;">Step1 : </div>
  <div style="float: left;
    width: 91%;"> I am a boy................. <br>my name is Ram</div>
</div>
<div class="steps">
  <div style="color:#BB2812;    float: left;
    width: 8%;">Step2 : </div>
  <div style="float: left;
    width: 91%;">There are many countries but I live in Australia </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a solution that can be achieved the best by modifying dt/dd with grid lay-out. Here's an example:

```css
.steps {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.5em 0;
  
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
.steps dt {
  color: #BB2812;
}
.steps dt::after {
  content: ' : ';
}
```

```html
<dl class="steps">
  <dt>Step 1</dt>
  <dd>I am a boy.................<br>my name is Ram</dd>
  <dt>Step 2</dt>
  <dd>There are many countries but I live in Australia</dd>
</dl>
```